# SwiftAudio.modulemap' not found - React native tracker player project error in ios

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, react-native

I get this error when try xCode build ios

> fatal error: module map file
> '/Users/waleed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-atqgmsmfarjhneesccxbrxpittbw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftAudio/SwiftAudio.modulemap'
> not found 1 error generated.
> Blockquote

project run fine in react-native run-ios but not working when run from xcode

Answer (score 0):

SwiftAudio is on Cocoapods.
Is your project / pod correct initialized?

You need
`pod 'SwiftAudio', ~> '0.11.2'`

in your Cocoapods File.